# Hide parent DIV if <li> is Empty

Tags: jquery

I know this has got to be incredibly simple but I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. My HTML is:

```
<div class="awardsparent">
<h4>AWARDS</h4>
<ul class="awards"><li></li></ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide the container div.awardsparent if the ul.awards li is empty. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {          
  if($('ul.awards li:empty')) {
  $('div.awardsparent').hide();
    }
});
```

Thank you! Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you probably don't even need the if test, just let jQuery's empty selectors do the magic.

This one liner should do it.

`$("ul.awards li:empty").closest('div.awardsparent').hide()`

**Edit:** and by empty selector I mean that if `$("ul.awards li:empty")` returns something then it will hide the parent, but if the selection is empty it will silently ignore the `closest()` as there is nothing to apply it to.

Comment: Definitely, as this will allow having multiple divisions with the `awardsparent` class, without affecting them all.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if ($('ul.awards li').is(':empty')) {
    $('div.awardsparent').hide();
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z6HeG/)**

Comment: This doesn't work if you have one div.awardsparent with empty li and another one with a non-empty li. They both get hidden.

Comment: OP didn't specify more than one div.awardsparent.

Comment: Well, it's not really bullet proof

Answer (score 1):

try using `.length`, as in:

```
if ($("ul.awards li:empty").length)
```