# Hide Parent Div if nested div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the outer div when a nested div is empty (including white-space node). I've found a solution that works if there is NO whitespace:
[Hide parent DIV if <li> is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829190/hide-parent-div-if-li-is-empty)

I need it to work when there IS white space present, ie:

```
  <div class="gen-customer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="heading">Hidden if working 1</div>
       <div class="content">
      <div class="product"> </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuz6x/34/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuz6x/36/)**

You could use the both `:empty` and `:contain()` selector :

```
$("div.product:contains(' '), div.product:empty").closest('div.wrapper').hide();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("div.product:contains(' '), div.product:empty").closest('div.wrapper').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Hidden if working 1</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Visible if working 2</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Hidden if working 3</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! The othe rawsers worked as well. I was also heading towards the trim method, but this jus seems closer to my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each `div.product` and trim the text to remove whitespace.  If there's anything left, show it, otherwise, hide its wrapper.

```js
$("div.product").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == '') {
    $(this).closest('div.wrapper').hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Hidden if working 1</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Visible if working 2</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gen-customer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">Hidden if working 3</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**//Try this using Jquery**

```
<script>

    //A perfect reference in Jquery...
    var element=$('#target_child');
    if($(element).html()==''){
        $(element).parent().hide()
    }else{
        //do some work
    }

</script>
```